# Allow apps to be linked to your account

Tags: feature-request, user-accounts, stackapps

I often use Stack Exchange on different machines, but installing the [apps](https://stackapps.com/) I use and keeping them up to date on all of them is a bit of a pain (and I occasionally use Stack Exchange on someone else' machine, where I don't really want to clutter the machine with apps).

Can't we allow a few apps to be linked to one's account so these are active where-ever you're logged in?

These apps could exist on the server, so each user will literally just have a few unique IDs to indicate which apps they use.

We could either have the unique ID link to a specific version of an app (and leave updating to the user - the simplest approach, or prompt them to update), or the unique ID could link to an app and we could auto-update it (shouldn't be too difficult either, but bugs in new versions could lead to lots of irritation).